# spring boot and react-use-websocket message not received in React TS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket

i am using spring boot with WebSocket to send message to a react TS application.

spring boot code =>

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageService {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000L)
    public void send(){

        System.out.println("message sent");
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/message", "message from spring server...");
    }
}
```

==============================

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

}

in react i used => npm i react-use-websocket

code here =>

```
    import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useWebSocket, { ReadyState } from "react-use-websocket";

const url = "ws:localhost:8080/ws";

const Web = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  const handleMessage = (msg: any) => {
    console.log("message: " + msg);
  };

  const { lastMessage, readyState, sendMessage } = useWebSocket(url, {
    onOpen: () => console.log("web socket opened"),
    onClose: () => console.log("connection closed"),
    shouldReconnect: (closeEvent) => true,
    onMessage: (event: any) => handleMessage(event),
  });

  const handleSend = () => {
    useCallback(() => sendMessage("message hello"), []);
  };

  const connectionStatus = {
    [ReadyState.CONNECTING]: "Connecting",
    [ReadyState.OPEN]: "Open",
    [ReadyState.CLOSING]: "Closing",
    [ReadyState.CLOSED]: "Closed",
    [ReadyState.UNINSTANTIATED]: "Uninstantiated",
  }[readyState];

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("received");
    setMessage(lastMessage?.data);
  }, [lastMessage]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Web Socket Application</div>
      <p>message received: {lastMessage?.data}</p>
      <p>{readyState}</p>
      <p>{connectionStatus}</p>
      <button onClick={handleSend}>send message</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Web;
```

the connection is open as i can see from the ReadyState provided by react-use-websocket but i am not receiving the messages.

please advise. thanks in advance